# Passing CakeContext to another .cake file

Tags: c#, cakebuild

I use CAKE 0.21.1.0.

My `build.cake` script loads another `.cake` script: `tests.cake`.

In `tests.cake`, I have a class called `TestRunner`. `TestRunner` has a method called `RunUnitTests()`, which executes unit tests using the `VSTest` method [provided by CAKE](https://www.cakebuild.net/dsl/vstest/).

In `build.cake`, I create several instances of `TestRunner`. Whenever I invoke the `RunUnitTests()` method on any one of the instances, I see the following error message:

```
error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'VSTest(IEnumerable<FilePath>, VSTestSettings)'
```

I think this is because I need to call `VSTest` on an explicit instance of `CakeContext` in `tests.cake`.

My question is: How can I ensure that my `tests.cake` script shares the same `CakeContext` instance as my `build.cake` script? What should I do to get `tests.cake` to compile?

**EDIT:**

In response to [devlead's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46485602/3559686), I have decided to add more information.

I followed devlead's suggestion and changed my `RunUnitTests()` method signature to:

```
public void RunUnitTests(ICakeContext context)
```

In `build.cake`, one of my tasks does the following:

```
TestRunner testRunner = TestRunnerAssemblies[testRunnerName];
testRunner.RunUnitTests(this);
```

where `TestRunnerAssemblies` is a read-only dictionary in `tests.cake`, and `testRunnerName` is a previously-defined variable. (In `build.cake`, I have inserted `#l "tests.cake"`.)

Now I see this error message:

```
error CS0027: Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Never mind, I need to learn how to read more carefully. Instead of passing in `this`, I passed in `Context` instead, as devlead originally suggested. Now the `RunUnitTests` method can be invoked without issue.

Comment: Don't use `this`, instead, use `Context` as shown here: https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Recipe/blob/develop/setup.cake#L13 and also, as shown in @devlead example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `RunUnitTests()` is a static method or in a class you'll need to pass the context as an parameter to it like `RunUnitTests(ICakeContext context)` because it's a different scope.

And then you can execute aliases as an extension on that methods.

Example:

```
RunUnitTests(Context);

public static void RunUnitTests(ICakeContext context)
{
    context.VSTest(...)
}
```

Example with class:

```
Task("Run-Unit-Tests")
    .Does(TestRunner.RunUnitTests);

RunTarget("Run-Unit-Tests");


public static class TestRunner
{
    public static void RunUnitTests(ICakeContext context)
    {
        context.VSTest("./Tests/*.UnitTests.dll");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, devlead! I have made some updates to my post in response to your reply.

Comment: Don't send `this` send `Context` if you read my first example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to learn how to read more carefully :-)

Comment: Excellent, great it got sorted ;)